# C# Replace File in System32 Unauthorized Access

Tags: c#, wpf, replace, file-permissions, system32

I am trying to replace a file in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory but it won't work.

(For them who mean my program is a virus: No, it isn't!)

Some information about the environment:

- Windows 7 SP1
- Visual Studio 2012
- C# WPF Program

I've already added the application manifest and changed the `requestedExecutionLevel`.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

I have also tried to use a BATCH to replace the file but I get the same error.

Is there any way to replace the file?

For example explicitly ask for `FileIOPermissions.Write` or `.AllAccess`.

Comment: Is your system a 64 bit system?

Comment: _What_ file are you trying to replace? What error is "won't work"?

Comment: Make sure the file is not in use. If the file is being used by some process, there's no way you can overwrite it. Use the WinApi MoveFileEx command to do a replacement on reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system is 64 bit, but your application is 32 bit, this may help. From Dalong Zhang's answer to the [Can't copy files under C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config by C#](http://forums.iis.net/t/1193262.aspx) question on the Microsoft forum:

> Because so many applications have hard-coded the System32 directory name into paths, MS put the 64-bit systems files there instead of in a 'System64' directory.  The 32-bit versions now go into a 'SysWOW64' directory. but in order to prevent breaking 32-bit programs, the system performs a redirection by default for 32-bit processes trying to access the 'System32' directory. In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64.
>
> A simple way to get around this redirection is to use %windir%\Sysnative instead of %windir%\System32. Win64 will 'redirect' that directory to the actual System32 directory.
>
> You can use the `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()` API to completely disable this redirection. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx for details

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried it and it seems to work. (With sysnative!)